# Obtain a button knowing its name

Tags: java

I have a ButtonGroup, which contains 26 JButtons:
JButton A = new JButton("A");
JButton B = new JButton("B");
.....
JButton Z = new JButton("Z").

If I have a character c, char c = one of the 26 letters,
for example c = 'A', and I want to remove JButton A from the ButtonGroup, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I am thinking about passing a JButton itself as an argument in the function call

Comment: I think I actually solved my function another way around, by passing the JButton itself as an argument, so I know which JButton I am working with. Many Thanks!

Comment: Add tags or verbiage to indicate your user-interface kit. Swing?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solve this by passing the JButton itself as an argument instead of the Text of the button, so that I can know which button I am dealing with.